# Making Source writable from the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, ide

Is it possible to make readonly source code (eg., .pas & .dfm) writable from within the Delphi IDE?  The right click option to make files Readonly/Writable within the IDE doesn't change the properties on the file system.  Is there an IDE extension or similar that can achieve this?

A way to do this without having to integrate a source control system would be preferable.  I am using Delphi XE and Delphi 6.

Thanks!

sse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

Create a new package which will be installed into the IDE at designtime. If you have an existing package handy then you could carry on using it. Make sure the package `requires` the `designide` package. You can do this in the project manager, or just by viewing the project source and adding `designide` to the `requires` clause.

Now add the following unit to your package.

```
unit MakeEditable;

interface

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Menus, ToolsAPI;

type
  TMakeEditable = class(TObject)
  private
    FEditorServices: IOTAEditorServices;
    FFileMenu: TMenuItem;
    FMakeEditable: TMenuItem;
    function MenuItemWithCaptionLike(const Menu: TMenuItem; const DesiredCaption: string): TMenuItem;
    procedure MakeEditableClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMakeEditable.Create;
var
  Index: Integer;
  PreviousMenuItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  inherited;
  FEditorServices := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAEditorServices);
  FFileMenu := MenuItemWithCaptionLike((BorlandIDEServices as INTAServices40).MainMenu.Items, 'File');
  if Assigned(FFileMenu) then begin
    PreviousMenuItem := MenuItemWithCaptionLike(FFileMenu, 'Reopen');
    if Assigned(PreviousMenuItem) then begin
      Index := PreviousMenuItem.MenuIndex;
      if Index>=0 then begin
        FMakeEditable := TMenuItem.Create(FFileMenu);
        FMakeEditable.Caption := 'Ma&ke Editable';
        FMakeEditable.OnClick := MakeEditableClick;
        FFileMenu.Insert(Index, FMakeEditable);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TMakeEditable.Destroy;
begin
  FMakeEditable.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TMakeEditable.MenuItemWithCaptionLike(const Menu: TMenuItem; const DesiredCaption: string): TMenuItem;
var
  i: Integer;
  Target, Found: string;
begin
  Target := StringReplace(LowerCase(Trim(DesiredCaption)), '&', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  for i := 0 to Menu.Count-1 do begin
    Result := Menu.Items[i];
    Found := StringReplace(LowerCase(Trim(Result.Caption)), '&', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    if Pos(Target, Found)>0 then begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;

procedure TMakeEditable.MakeEditableClick(Sender: TObject);

  procedure MakeFileEditable(const FileName: string);
  var
    Attributes: DWORD;
  begin
    Attributes := GetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName));
    SetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName), Attributes and not FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
  end;

var
  FileName: string;
  FileExt: string;
  LinkedFileName: string;
  EditBuffer: IOTAEditBuffer;

begin
  EditBuffer := FEditorServices.TopBuffer;
  FileName := EditBuffer.FileName;
  if FileExists(FileName) then begin
    MakeFileEditable(FileName);
    EditBuffer.IsReadOnly := False;

    FileExt := ExtractFileExt(FileName);
    if SameText(FileExt,'.dfm') then begin
      LinkedFileName := ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.pas');
    end else if SameText(FileExt,'.pas') then begin
      LinkedFileName := ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.dfm');
    end else begin
      LinkedFileName := '';
    end;
    if (LinkedFileName<>'') and FileExists(LinkedFileName) then begin
      MakeFileEditable(LinkedFileName);
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  MakeEditableInstance: TMakeEditable;

procedure Register;
begin
  MakeEditableInstance := TMakeEditable.Create;
end;

initialization

finalization
  MakeEditableInstance.Free;

end.
```

When you compile and install this package you will now have a new menu item on the File menu which both clears the read-only flag in the input buffer and makes the file writeable.

[image]

Comment: +1, this a good way to show how to build a package with IDE menu :)

Comment: +1. In order to handle the main program/package file also add .dpr and .dpk file check. And here you should also change the RO attribute for the .dproj and .res files.

Comment: @larsdk good point. This code was driven by our use of a legacy vcs and we never made those files read only. So that's why it is the way it is. Still, the code above provides a useful template I hope.

Comment: FYI: in XE3 I had to change the uses clause to use `Vcl.Menus` (instead of `Menus`)

Answer (score 3):

You can call a .bat file from the tools menu.  So you could write a .bat file to do the work for  you, and call it with $EDNAME as the parameter.
Your .bat file should see the filename as %1.  Then you'd need a little bit of logic to change the read-only flag (attrib command?) and then see if there is a .dfm and do that one as well.

You could also (obviously) make a Delphi command-line app to do this, if you're not comfortable with .bat files.

This idea inspired by this article that talks about how to use a .bat file to integrate SVN commands with the Delphi tools menu:
http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_TortoiseSVN_to_the_Tools_menu

Comment: unless you do it from a package I know of no way to toggle the editor's read only flag

Comment: The OPs question was about changing the read-only attribute on the disk file, not the editor.

Comment: And from personal experience one without the other isn't satisfactory.

Comment: <shrug>  For me, having my source files being read-only isn't satisfactory either.  Likewise with having no version control system.

Comment: I agree. My recent migration to SVN has liberated my from such annoyances.

Comment: There are times when it is useful to make something writable outside of sourcecontrol.

Comment: Chris, I actually implemented your solution in a console app.  It also works well.  David's ties into the IDE more nicely though.  Thank you!

Comment: also, +1 for a nice flexible and lightweight approach

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: Just add an option to the tools menu: "open command prompt here". It lets you do all sorts of things from the command line, such as running the attrib command.

Add a new entry to the Tools menu, and use these settings:

```
Title: Open Command Prompt Here
Program: cmd.exe
Working Dir (leave blank)
Parameters:  cd $PATH($EDNAME)
```

Also, make yourself an "Open Folder Here" entry:

```
Title: Open Folder Here
Program: explorer.exe
Working Dir (leave blank)
Parameters: $PATH($EDNAME)
```